# Is it possible to use Impala in Hadoop 1 (without YARN)?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-yarn, impala

I saw in Hadoop 1 limitations that the only paradigm we can use is mapreduce. If you want to use other paradigms (like spark for instance), you have to use Hadoop 2.0 and YARN.

But i have a question related to Impala. Was it possible to use Impala without YARN or not ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Impala can be used independently of YARN.

Comment: so why do people say that with Hadoop 1, the only paradigm that we can use is MapReduce ? Is it a mistake to say that ?

Comment: Core Hadoop contains 2 pieces:  MapReduce and HDFS.  Applications like Impala, Spark, Oryx, etc. utilize the HDFS component of Hadoop, but not MR.  What YARN provides with Hadoop 2 is a generic resource negotiator that the other services can leverage for centralized resource sharing, management and clustering.